# Qt compile error: C2280: attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a relatively simple class that contains a layout with a few widgets (labels, lineEdits, pushButtons) that gets displayed as a card. It all works fine until I try to add signals and slots. The header file, below, compiles fine with the sections commented-out as shown.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>

class KMLFile //: public QObject
{
    //Q_OBJECT
public:
    KMLFile();
    ~KMLFile();

    QString m_originalFilename;
    QString m_originalPath;
    QString m_proposedFilename;
    QString m_propsoedPath;
    QString m_coords;
    QWidget* trackWidget;

    void populate(QString originalFilename, QString originalPath, QString proposedFilename, QString coords);
    QString getCoords();
    int getLength();

//public slots:
    //void changeFilename();

};
```

When those bits of code are left in, I get the following error:

> "C:...\qlist.h:425: error: C2280: 'KMLFile::KMLFile(const KMLFile &)':
>   attempting to reference a deleted function

I am using Qt5.3 and Qt Creator. I have tried cleaning, running qmake and deleting the build folder to no avail. I'm stumped!

Grateful for any insight into how to fix this so that I can progress.

Comment: You can't use Qt's signals/slots mechanism without inheriting from QObject and without using the Q_OBJECT macro and running your code through the "moc" meta-object-compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The copy constructor of `QObject` is private - or deleted.

Somewhere else in your code you use the copy constructor of `KMLFile`, which then calls the copy constructor of `QObject`.

You could reimplement the copy constructor of `KMLFile`, but the best solution is to not use it at all.

In your `QList` you should store pointers to the `KMLFile` objects instead of the objects themselves provided that they will live longer than the list itself. Or you can start using `QSharedPointer`.

Comment: Thanks very much, this gave me just enough to work out how to solve the problem. I changed the declaration of my QList to `QList<KMLFile*> tracks;` and instantiate objects of it with `KMLFile *track = new KMLFile;`, and it now compiles fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SeaMouse be careful. You need to delete them at one point or another. Giving a parent to each `KMLFile` (presumably in the member function of the `QObject` inheritor which holds the list) takes care of most of the problem, but doing a `qDeleteAll()` on the list before it's destroyed can also solve it.

Comment: thanks for the reminder - I had forgotten to do that!

Comment: I wanted my object to have a signal, but it was in a QVector of another class.  Once I made it a QVector of pointers, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

[QObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html) has a deleted copy constructor. Your class is creating a compiler generated copy constructor. When you make `QObject` a base of your class the compiler generated copy constructor for `KLMFile` attempts to call the deleted copy constructor of the base class and that is when you get an error.

The copy constructor for `KLMFile` will be automatically generated if required (ie if you try copy an instance of the class) unless you explicitly specify a copy constructor of your own.

If the line referenced in the error is near a copy of the `KLMFile` class that would be a strong indicator that this is the case.