# QT : attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: qt, qt5, c++14

I know this question has been asked numerous time ([there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396950/qt-compile-error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264984/c-compiler-error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-in-visual) for example) but unfortunately, those solutions are not working for my case.

### Background

Error message: `'ADACEL::SPEECH::SRA::StatusRow::StatusRow(const ADACEL::SPEECH::SRA::StatusRow &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

From my reading, I understand that the problem could be from the copy constructor of QObject, but I don't know how to fix this!

---

**So, see my classe**  :

```
namespace ADACEL
{
    namespace SPEECH
    {
        namespace SRA 
        {
            class StatusRow: public QObject
            {
                Q_OBJECT
                Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
                Q_PROPERTY(QString icon READ icon WRITE setIcon NOTIFY iconChanged)

            public:
                StatusRow(QObject *parent = 0);
                StatusRow(const QString &name, const QString &color, QObject *parent = 0);
                //StatusRow(const StatusRow&) = delete;   
                ~StatusRow(void) {};

                QString name() const;
                void setName(const QString &name);

                QString icon() const;
                void setIcon(const QString &icon);

                //StatusRow& operator=(const StatusRow&) = delete; 

            Q_SIGNALS:
                void nameChanged();
                void iconChanged();

            private:
                QString m_name;
                QString m_icon;
            };
        }
    }
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ADACEL::SPEECH::SRA::StatusRow)
```

---

**Instantiation of my classe**:

```
StatusWindow::StatusWindow(GUIDataLayer* pUiDataLayer) : QDeclarativeView(0),
                                                         m_statusRows(0)
{
    setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);

    m_statusRows = new QList<StatusRow*>();
    m_statusRows->append(new StatusRow(TITLE_AUDIO_PROVIDER, ICON_OK));
    m_statusRows->append(new StatusRow(TITLE_ADAPTER, ICON_ERROR));

    rootContext()->setContextProperty("statusInfo", QVariant::fromValue(m_statusRows));
    rootContext()->setContextProperty("uiDataLayer", pUiDataLayer);
...
}
```

---

### What I tried so far

I already tried this `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ADACEL::SPEECH::SRA::StatusRow*)` but then I have the error `Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system`

Also, `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is only necessary when I am using a pointer into the QVariant.  The following is compiling without any problem :

```
QList<StatusRow*> statusRows;
statusRows.append(new StatusRow(TITLE_AUDIO_PROVIDER, ICON_OK));
statusRows.append(new StatusRow(TITLE_ASR_ENGINE, ICON_NONE));
statusRows.append(new StatusRow(TITLE_POST_PROCESSOR, ICON_NONE));
statusRows.append(new StatusRow(TITLE_ADAPTER, ICON_ERROR));
rootContext()->setContextProperty("statusInfo", QVariant::fromValue(statusRows));
```

Comment: @eyllanesc Thx.a.lot! your solution worked for me.  Also, I think my problem was that I was using a pointer `QList<T*>*`

Comment: **the copy constructor of QObject**  [QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not observe the error you indicate, I also prefer to use `QVariantList` instead of `QList <T* >` to export a list of `QObjects`:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
using namespace ADACEL::SPEECH::SRA;

QVariantList statusRows;
statusRows.append(QVariant::fromValue(new StatusRow("TITLE_AUDIO_PROVIDER", "ICON_OK")));
statusRows.append(QVariant::fromValue(new StatusRow("TITLE_ASR_ENGINE", "ICON_NONE")));
statusRows.append(QVariant::fromValue(new StatusRow("TITLE_POST_PROCESSOR", "ICON_NONE")));
statusRows.append(QVariant::fromValue(new StatusRow("TITLE_ADAPTER", "ICON_ERROR")));

QQuickView view;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("statusInfo", QVariant::fromValue(statusRows));
```